# Only allow specific user access to s3 folder. make private to everyone else

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have tried to deny overall access, and then give specific access to a provided user which happens to be the application.  I am executing PUT and GET requests using the AWS service API.

I have tried the following, but since I have a deny GET on all users, it will not let the allowed user do a GET request even though it is stated in the policy.

Ideally I would like to allow access to a specific group.  I tried using the following , but the bucket policy wouldn't save stating 'Invalid principal in policy - '
arn:aws:iam::222222222222:group/Admin

I would also rather server private content over cloudfront and make the s3 buckets private.  Option #2
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Is there a better way to this where I deny all access to everyone except specified users?

```
{
"Sid": "force deny access to private folder",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Principal": {
  "AWS": "*"
},
"Action": "s3:GetObject",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/apptest/*"
```

},

```
{
  "Sid": "allow s3 uplaod and conversion using aws-sdk",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/user_name"
  },
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
    "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
    "s3:GetObjectAcl",
    "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
    "s3:RestoreObject",
    "s3:GetObjectVersion",
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/apptest/*"}
```

Answer (score 0):

My money is this will answer your question before I get to you monday on codementor.

Stop using s3 policy and use IAM instead.

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc

If not, i'll see you monday!

Comment: If I remove the all bucket policies, wouldnt that restrict anonymous user access?  I am serving images using cloudfront.

Comment: Not if you create an IAM to handle it. Anon in the base folder, IAM to protect the child folder.